# Sleep program for half a second in C on Linux

Tags: c, linux, sleep, curses

I just can't find a way to sleep my program or just make it wait for a set amount of miliseconds, I tried sleep() but it only works for full seconds, usleep() is giving implicit declaration error and correcting it to sleep(), nanosleep() also only pauses it for full seconds.

```
while(1){
        wclear(win);
        box(win, 0, 0);
        mvwprintw(win, 0, anim, "Snake");
        wrefresh(win);

        sleep(500);

        if(intro == 3){
            if(anim < 53) anim++;
            else intro--;
        }
        if(intro == 2){
            if(anim > 2) anim--;
            else intro--;
        }
        if(intro == 1){
            if(anim < 23) anim++;
            else intro--;
        }
        if(intro == 0) break;
    }
```

All I want is to make a smooth little animation, but no matter what library I use or what kind of sleep function I use, it will either do full seconds which is too long, or 0 seconds (so nothing), or throw errors.

Comment: *usleep() is giving implicit declaration error* - Did you try `man usleep` and looking at which header file needs to be included for it?

Comment: _`usleep()` is giving implicit declaration error_ . The first comment notwithstanding, did you [`#include <unistd.h>`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/usleep.3.html)

Comment: I did include <unistd.h> while using usleep() / sleep() but usleep() would always give me implicit declaration error.

Comment: the MAN page for usleep() says" `usleep():
           Since glibc 2.12:
               (_XOPEN_SOURCE >= 500) && ! (_POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200809L)
                   || /* Glibc since 2.19: */ _DEFAULT_SOURCE
                   || /* Glibc versions <= 2.19: */ _BSD_SOURCE
           Before glibc 2.12:
               _BSD_SOURCE || _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 500`with out an appropriate macro being defined, the prototype for `usleep()` will not be defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some ideas to explore why `usleep` isn't working out. `select` is another popular way to delay for periods of time.

```c
#include <unistd.h>
int main( )
{
  int i;
  for ( i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ ) usleep(100000);
  return 0;
}
```

Also, try using the compiler to reveal where `unistd.h` is coming from, like this for `gcc`

```
gcc -H main.c 
. /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/unistd.h
. . . MORE . . .
```

Another helping idea is to output the preprocessor output like this:

```
gcc -E main.c 

# 1 "main.c"
# 1 "<built-in>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 3
# 370 "<built-in>" 3
# 1 "<command line>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 2
# 1 "main.c" 2
# 1 "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/unistd.h" 1 3 4
# 71 "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/unistd.h" 3 4

. . . MORE . . .
```

Here is some code that uses `select` to create a timeout.

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main( )
{
  fd_set set;
  struct timeval timeout;
  FD_ZERO(&set);
  timeout.tv_sec = 0;
  timeout.tv_usec = 100000;
  if (0==select(FD_SETSIZE, &set, NULL, NULL, &timeout)) printf("timeout\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's absolutely no reason to use `select` for a simple delay operation. Use `usleep` and be done with it.